# PHP Convert Simple 3 Line JavaScript to PHP Equivalent

Tags: javascript, php

I've been provided with a few lines of JavaScript that I need to convert to the PHP equivalent. Not being a JavaScript developer I'm struggling with this. Here's the JavaScript sample I've been provided:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const secret_in_hex = Buffer.from(secret, 'hex');

const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', secret_in_hex)
  .update(body)
  .digest('hex')

// Compare hash with the received X-Onfleet-Signature in raw bytes
```

The [docs](https://docs.onfleet.com/reference#secrets) for the API I'm working with to setup a Webhook receiver in PHP mention:

`Each webhook request contains a signature from Onfleet in X-Onfleet-Signature header. To authenticate the webhook request received on your webhook server, you will need to validate against this header. To validate against X-Onfleet-Signature, you will need to compare its value with an HMAC you have generated using the hexadecimal format of your webhook secrets and the full body of the webhook POST request in raw bytes.`

I'm assuming I'll be using the `hash_hmac` function and possibly the `bin2hex` function but completely stumped at this point and appreciate if someone can show me the PHP equivalent of the above JavaScript (assuming there is one).

Comment: `hash('sha512', $hashString)` is PHP for `sha512`. That's about all I can do for you.

Comment: You probably need this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest equivalent should be:

```
$secretInHex = hex2bin($secret);
$hash = hash_hmac('sha512', $body, $secretInHex);
```

You should note that [hex2bin](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) function **does NOT convert a hexadecimal number to a binary number but it decodes a hexadecimally encoded binary string**.

So the secret provided should already be a hexadecimal else `hex2bin` will throw an exception